# How to "de-stringify" pickled object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I need do serialize a pickle object and cast it as a string. What type of cast do I need to deserialize it with `pickle.loads()`? `bytes()` and `bytearray()` didn't work... I also need to use python 3, so cPickle ain't am option.

```
import pickle

hallo = {'lol': 1, 'lel': 2}

hallo = str(pickle.dumps(hallo))
hallo = pickle.loads(bytes(hallo)) # how to cast correctly?

print(hallo)
```

Comment: What is the reason you "need do serialize a pickle object and *cast it as a string*"?

Comment: I need to send a custom object via ROS Publisher and receive it via ROS Subscriber. ROS only supports standard datatypes like Int16, Float32 and String. In order to send my object around I need to serialize it and than cast it as a String in order to send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert literal representations of values back to their initial value, such as produced by calling `str` on a `bytes` object.

```py
import ast
import pickle

hallo = {'lol': 1, 'lel': 2}

hallo = str(pickle.dumps(hallo))
hallo = pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval(hallo))

print(hallo)  # {'lol': 1, 'lel': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this did it for me! As I was using ROS somehow the default pickle protocol worked for this simple example but not for ROS Publisher and Subscirber. I had to use ```hallo = pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval(hallo, protocol=2))``` in order to work. :)